# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript

O trecho de código abaixo está dando erro pois _elemento está retornando null alguma idéia de como resolver?

```js
class View {

    constructor(seletor) {

        this._elemento = document.querySelector(seletor);
    }

    update(model) {

        this._elemento.innerHTML = this.template(model);
    }

    template(model) {

        throw new Error('Você precisa implementar o método template');
    }
}
```

```js
class NegociacoesView extends View {

    template(model) {

        return `
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>DATA</th>
                    <th>QUANTIDADE</th>
                    <th>VALOR</th>
                    <th>VOLUME</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            
            <tbody>
                ${model.paraArray().map(negociacao =>
                `
                    <tr>
                        <td>${DateConverter.paraTexto(negociacao.data)}</td>
                        <td>${negociacao.quantidade}</td>
                        <td>${negociacao.valor}</td>
                        <td>${negociacao.volume}</td>
                    </tr>                        
                `).join('')}
            </tbody>
            
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                    <td>${model.volumeTotal}</td>            
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            
        </table>               
        `
    }
}
```

```js
class MensagemView extends View {

    template(model) {

        return model.texto
            ? `<p class="alert alert-info">${model.texto}</p>`
            : `<p></p>`;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">    
    <title>Negociações</title>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    

</head>

<body class="container">

    <h1 class="text-center">Negociações</h1>

    <div class="mensagemView"></div>

    <form class="form">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="data">Data</label>
            <input type="date" id="data" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="quantidade">Quantidade</label>
            <input type="number" min="1" step="1" id="quantidade" class="form-control" value="1" required/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="valor">Valor</label>
            <input id="valor" type="number" class="form-control" min="0.01" step="0.01" value="0.0" required />
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Incluir</button>
    </form>

    <div class="text-center">
        <button id="botao-importa" class="btn btn-primary text-center" type="button">
            Importar Negociações
        </button>
        <button id="botao-apaga" class="btn btn-primary text-center" type="button">
            Apagar
        </button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    
    <div id="negociacoes"></div> 
    <script src="app/domain/negociacao/Negociacao.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/NegociacaoController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/ui/converters/DateConverter.js"></script>
    <script src="app/domain/negociacao/Negociacoes.js"></script>
    <script src="app/ui/views/View.js"></script>
    <script src="app/ui/views/NegociacoesView.js"></script> 
    <script src="app/ui/models/Mensagem.js"></script>
    <script src="app/ui/views/MensagemView.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Posta o código onde você tentar usar o método `update`.

Comment: Posta o código em que você cria uma `new View`. E o código HTML que vai junto. Se não for erro no seletor, pode ser que o elemento ainda não exista no momento em que você roda esse código.

Comment: na verdade as views q criei herdam essa class view

Comment: acredito q tudo oque vc precisa pra me ajudar está aqui

Comment: acredito que descobri o erro rsrsrs e ta no html

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade no meu código o original #mensagemView estava sendo chamado como .mensagemView por isso nao funcionava

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">    
    <title>Negociações</title>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    

</head>

<body class="container">

    <h1 class="text-center">Negociações</h1>

    <div id="mensagemView"></div>

    <form class="form">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="data">Data</label>
            <input type="date" id="data" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="quantidade">Quantidade</label>
            <input type="number" min="1" step="1" id="quantidade" class="form-control" value="1" required/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="valor">Valor</label>
            <input id="valor" type="number" class="form-control" min="0.01" step="0.01" value="0.0" required />
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Incluir</button>
    </form>

    <div class="text-center">
        <button id="botao-importa" class="btn btn-primary text-center" type="button">
            Importar Negociações
        </button>
        <button id="botao-apaga" class="btn btn-primary text-center" type="button">
            Apagar
        </button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    
    <div id="negociacoes"></div> 
    <script src="app/domain/negociacao/Negociacao.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/NegociacaoController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/ui/converters/DateConverter.js"></script>
    <script src="app/domain/negociacao/Negociacoes.js"></script>
    <script src="app/ui/views/View.js"></script>
    <script src="app/ui/views/NegociacoesView.js"></script> 
    <script src="app/ui/models/Mensagem.js"></script>
    <script src="app/ui/views/MensagemView.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```